# Changing encoding in idea intellij doesn't work

Tags: java, intellij-idea, encoding, notepad++

I have a .java file with a string `String s="P�rsh�ndetje bot�!";`.

When I open this file in `Notepad++` and change encoding to ISO-8859-1 it shows appropriate string: `"Përshëndetje botë!"`, but if i open the file in idea intellij and change encoding to ISO-8859-1, it gives me a warning of how some symbols can't be converted and then replaces those symbols with `?` mark: `"P?rsh?ndetje bot?!"`.

Why is this happening? Why Notepad++ is able to convert the file, while idea is not?

Comment: Why not use UTF-8 directly? Maybe Intellij has issues with your selected encoding?

Comment: @bureaquete, UTF-8 doesn't work with this file. Notepad++ and Intellij both have default UTF-8 and for characters to be shown it needs to be changed.

Comment: Do you use File > File Encoding > `ISO-8859-1` > Convert ?
With those steps, I had no issue on my intellij

Comment: @bureaquete, Yes. It gives me two warnings: `The encoding you've chosen may change the contents of the file...` and `Please do not convert to 'ISO-8859-1'. Encoding 'ISO-8859-1' does not support some characters from the text`.

Comment: Just click `convert`, does that break anything in your file then?

Comment: @bureaquete, Yes, I click 'Convert' twice ad then it replaces non-UTF-8 characters with question marks (but those should be letters 'ë').

Comment: Twice, meaning you had that `Please do not convert ...` err message? And click convert on that err message also?

Comment: @bureaquete, Yes.

Comment: I am not sure of the reason sadly, mine works well, maybe something on your file, or on your IDE is breaking it somehow. Mine had no plugins nothing, and latest Community version

Comment: I'm not sure, but it is possible that when you first opened the file it was read as UTF-8 and the invalid byte sequences were turned into the [Unicode replacement character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm), then when you try to convert to ISO-8859-1 it is trying to convert the Unicode replacement character but there is no value for that in ISO-8859-1 so it is converted to `?` instead.

Comment: I think you need to get IntelliJ to *open* the file as ISO-8859-1, rather than opening it first as UTF-8 and then trying to *convert* to ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @davidconrad the byte sequences are not invalid in UTF-8 though, those Albanian ë's

Comment: @David Conra,Thanks, looks like this is working. I tried to open the file outside of the main project and the conversion worked! Then I figured just clicking 'Reload' when those 2 warnings appear does the trick. Thank you and bureaquete for your time.

Comment: @bureaquete Yes, they are invalid UTF-8 byte sequences. The ISO-8859-1 encoding of "ërs" is `EB` `72` `73` which is the start byte of a three-byte UTF-8 sequence, but the next two bytes are not continuation bytes. I guess what you mean is that "ërs" can be encoded with UTF-8 but that's not the same as saying that those Latin-1 bytes are a valid UTF-8 byte sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is some bug here in IDEA (where the default encoding is UTF-8) in that when you convert the file containing valid ISO-8859-1 encoded characters and change the file encoding to ISO-8859-1, it messes it up. The particular codepoint that it messes up is ë. For some reason, it replaces it with `\ufffd` whereas its correct codepoint is `\u00eb`. This is the character that shows up as � in your editor.

My suggestion is to just use UTF-8 and not change it to ISO-8859-1. UTF-8 is backward compatible with ISO-8859-1 and you could write this string using the IME on your OS (which appears to be Windows). I am not sure how to do it on Windows, but on a Mac, I use the U+ keyboard
[image]

and then add this character as 00eb while keeping the ALT key pressed. Then it shows up correctly:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, but it is possible that when you first opened the file it was read as UTF-8 and the invalid byte sequences were turned into the [Unicode replacement character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm), then when you try to convert to ISO-8859-1 it is trying to convert the Unicode replacement character but there is no value for that in ISO-8859-1 so it is converted to `?` instead.

(Even though text like "ërs" can be represented in Unicode and thus UTF-8, the ISO-8859-1 encoding of "ërs" is `EB` `72` `73` which is the start byte of a three-byte UTF-8 sequence, but the next two bytes are not continuation bytes, so a program treating it as UTF-8 would think those accented characters are invalid.)

I think you need to get IntelliJ to open the file as ISO-8859-1, rather than opening it first as UTF-8 and then trying to convert to ISO-8859-1.

(When you switch the encoding in Notepad++ it must be going back to the original bytes of the file and interpreting them as ISO-8859-1, rather than trying to convert content that it has already altered by changing invalid bytes to the replacement character.)

Note that ë is a perfectly valid Unicode character. It can be represented as either U+00EB, *Latin small letter e with diaeresis*, or as two code points, U+0065 and U+0308, *Latin small letter e* combined with *Combining diaeresis*. But U+00EB would be encoded in UTF-8 as the two-byte sequence `C3` `AB`, and for U+0065 U+0308 the "e" would be encoded as itself, `65`, and U+0308 would be encoded as `CC` `88`.

So "ë" in UTF-8 must be either `C3` `AB` or `65` `CC` `88`. It can't be `EB`.

Comment: Could you please explain also why when I convert the file back to UTF-8 the `ë` character doesn't get replaced with question marks again? How is that possible if there is no `ë` in UTF-8?

And why Intellij's output window displays the characters correctly, isn't the output out to be encoded in UTF-8?

Comment: There is an `ë` in UTF-8, it just can't be encoded as a single byte as in ISO-8859-1. I've update the answer with an explanation of the two ways `ë` can be correctly represented in UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you... But how is this happening? I mean, ISO-8859-1-->UTF-8 (when the file is opened the first time) damages the `ë`, and then the same thing when file is reloaded  as ISO-8859-1: ISO-8859-1-->UTF-8 works just fine...

Comment: I don't know exactly what is happening with IntelliJ, but as I said it seems that when opening it it was not converting it but merely interpreting it as a UTF-8 file with some invalid byte sequences in it. So it is not doing ISO-8859-1-->UTF-8 when the file is opened the first time. It is just doing UTF-8 -- Hey, this isn't valid UTF-8!